# Why don't my seedlings make true leaves?

Tags: tomatoes, seedlings, onions

I'm trying to start seedlings inside in order to lengthen my growing season (I live in northern New England). I have heating mats, and grow lights. I'm currently trying to start tomatoes, brussel sprouts, and onion. I planted them 6 weeks ago. I had no trouble getting them to sprout, and make seed leaves. They aren't leggy at all. But the growth seems to have stalled or stopped altogether. Can anyone advise why they aren't making true leaves?

Comment: What's your growing media? How often are you watering?

Comment: How big is the growing container? The light is close enough?

Comment: I'm using Perfect Landscape Seed Starting Mix. It says that it's an organic nursery-grade blend. I'm watering every day. I'm using 2x2x2 inch and 3x3 1/2 in (diameter by depth) seed starter pots. The light is very close -- probably around 2in.

Comment: https://laidbackgardener.blog/2021/11/11/how-to-use-a-grow-light-for-tomatoes/ mY be worth a read.  Ot talks about how much and what kind of light tomatos want.

Comment: Also, how warm is it?  Heat can make a big difference to growth rate - I think tomatos 'want" 24c...

Answer (score 1):

How long do you have your grow lights on each day? Try for 14 hours a day.

Comment: Hi Kate, is this answer based on anything?  Personal experience or a what you may have read.

Comment: @RohitGupta 14 hours is probably about right (but on the low end) based on my experience in growing nightshades in greemhouses.  Temperature certainly plays a part but lighting is definately a/the major factor.